# Moving from one workspace to other workspace windows by name

Tags: python, regex, x11, workspace, wmctrl

I would like to move application windows from one workspace to other worskpace.

#### What I want

If I have two workspaces `workspace1` and `workspace2`:

`workspace1`
old_test1
old_test2
new_test3

`workspace2`
new_test1
new_test2

#### What I did so far

I used `wmctrl` and it's working fine but I have to specify the entire name of the window that I want to move. I can move `new_test3` to `workspace2`.

However I would like to do something smarter, instead of have to put the whole name I want to use a regular expression (something like `wmctrl *new*` ) so all the windows that matches the regex *new* are moved to the workspace2.

**Do you know if there is a way of doing this?**

Many thanks

Comment: I think this will help you https://askubuntu.com/a/240454/52310

Comment: Apparently this solution is not working for me... the usage of regular expression does not seem to work with this code

Comment: Well sorry, than I think your best option is to create a bash or python scrip to list the windows oppened and then move them by some regular expression you desire